# How to create a custom reusable type in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping, elasticsearch-schema

My json for ElasticSearch schema looks like this :-

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "DESCRIPTION_FR": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "french"
      },
      "FEEDBACK_FR": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "french"
      },
      "SOURCE_FR": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "french"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*There are 100 of properties like this. Replicating a change across all the properties with this approach is redundant and erroneous.*

**Is there a way in ElasticSearch 7.2 to write custom data type and reuse it in property mapping.**

```
{
  "settings": {
  //definition of custom type "text_fr"
 },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "DESCRIPTION_FR": {
        "type": "text_fr"
      },
      "FEEDBACK_FR": {
        "type": "text_fr"
      },
      "SOURCE_FR": {
        "type": "text_fr"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! What you're after is [dynamic mapping templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html). More specifically the [`match` feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#match-unmatch).

1. Define the target field names with a leading wildcard:

```json
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "is_french_text": {
          "match_mapping_type": "*",
          "match": "*_FR",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "french"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

2. Insert a doc:

```json
POST my_index/_doc
{
  "DESCRIPTION_FR": "je",
  "FEEDBACK_FR": "oui",
  "SOURCE_FR": "je ne sais quoi"
}
```

3. Verify the dynamically generated mapping:

```json
GET my_index/_mapping
```